# Python C++ Bindings

Tags: python, c++, c++14, template

I wrote a very simple Python interface for C++ that uses the Python 2.7 C API. At the moment it can:

- Manage reference counts/deal with "stolen" references (`PyObject`)
- Load Python module
- Invoke a function (templated) and get result
- Convert between intrinsic Python and C++ types

**Notes**

I am not an expert in template meta-programming. Also, I wrote this project in approx. 6h today, so please take this into account. `PYObjectBase` could probably be implemented using a `std::unique_ptr` and a custom deleter, but for learning purpose I decided not to. I didn't comment much.

It should compile using MSVC (VS2017).

**Code**

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <Python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#else
#include <Python.h>
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace Scripting
{
    namespace Python
    {
        template<bool AUTO_RELEASE>
        class PYObjectBase
        {
        public:
            friend class PYObjectBase<!AUTO_RELEASE>;

            PYObjectBase(PyObject* a_Object)
                : m_Raw(a_Object)
            {
            }

            PYObjectBase()
                : PYObjectBase(nullptr)
            {
            }

            //COPY CTOR (DELETED)
            template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>
            PYObjectBase(const PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>& a_RHS) = delete;

            //MOVE CTOR
            template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>
            PYObjectBase(PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&& a_RHS)
            {
                m_Raw = a_RHS.m_Raw;
                a_RHS.m_Raw = nullptr;
            }

            //COPY ASSIGN (DELETED)
            template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>
            PYObjectBase<AUTO_RELEASE>& operator=(const PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&) = delete;

            //MOVE ASSIGN
            template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>
            PYObjectBase<AUTO_RELEASE>& operator=(const PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&& a_RHS)
            {
                m_Raw = a_RHS.m_Raw;
                a_RHS.m_Raw = nullptr;
                return *this;
            }

            PYObjectBase<AUTO_RELEASE>& operator=(PyObject* a_RHS)
            {
                m_Raw = a_RHS;
                return *this;
            }

            ~PYObjectBase()
            {
                if (AUTO_RELEASE && m_Raw != nullptr)
                    Py_DECREF(m_Raw);
            }

            operator PyObject*()
            {
                return m_Raw;
            }

        private:
            PyObject* m_Raw;
        };

        typedef PYObjectBase<true> PYObject;
        typedef PYObjectBase<false> PYWeakObject;

        template<typename...ARGS>
        class PYArgs
        {
        public:
            static constexpr size_t Size = sizeof...(ARGS);

            PYArgs(ARGS&&...args)
            {
                m_Tuple = PyTuple_New(Size);
                this->ConvertArgs(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
            }

            PYObject Expand()
            {
                return m_Tuple;
            }

        private:
            template<typename HEAD, typename...TAIL>
            void ConvertArgs(HEAD&& head, TAIL&&...tail)
            {
                this->SetArg<HEAD>(std::move(head), sizeof...(TAIL) - 1);
                this->ConvertArgs(std::forward<TAIL>(tail)...);
            }

            template<typename ARG>
            void ConvertArgs(ARG&& a_Arg)
            {
                this->SetArg<ARG>(std::move(a_Arg), Size - 1);
            }

            template<typename ARG>
            void SetArg(ARG&& a_Arg, const size_t a_Index)
            {
                std::cout << a_Index << "->" << a_Arg << std::endl;

                PYConverter<ARG> convert;
                PYWeakObject value = convert.from(a_Arg);

                PyTuple_SetItem(m_Tuple, a_Index, value);
            }

        private:
            PYObject m_Tuple;
        };

        template<typename...ARGS>
        PYArgs<ARGS...> PYMakeArgs(ARGS&&...a_Args)
        {
            return { std::forward<ARGS>(a_Args)... };
        }

        template<typename T>
        struct PYConverter;

        template<>
        struct PYConverter<int>
        {
            int to(PYObject obj)
            {
                return static_cast<int>(PyInt_AsLong(obj));
            }

            PYObject from(const int& v)
            {
                return PyInt_FromLong(static_cast<long>(v));
            }
        };

        template<>
        struct PYConverter<double>
        {
            double to(PYObject obj)
            {
                return PyFloat_AsDouble(obj);
            }

            PYObject from(const double& v)
            {
                return PyFloat_FromDouble(v);
            }
        };

        template<>
        struct PYConverter<std::string>
        {
            std::string to(PYObject obj)
            {
                return PyString_AsString(obj);
            }

            PYObject from(const std::string& v)
            {
                return PyString_FromString(v.c_str());
            }
        };

        class PYContext
        {
        public:
            PYContext(const std::string& a_Module = "__main__")
            {
                Py_Initialize();
                PYObject moduleStr = PyString_FromString(a_Module.c_str());
                m_Module = PyImport_Import(moduleStr);
            }

            ~PYContext()
            {
                Py_Finalize();
            }

            void Run(const std::string& a_Source)
            {
                PyRun_SimpleString(a_Source.c_str());
            }

            template<typename RETURN, typename...ARGS>
            RETURN Invoke(const std::string& a_Func, ARGS&&...a_Args)
            {
                PYObject func = PyObject_GetAttrString(m_Module, a_Func.c_str());
                if (!PyCallable_Check(func))
                    throw std::runtime_error("PyCallable_Check() failed!");

                auto args = PYMakeArgs(std::forward<ARGS>(a_Args)...);
                PYObject ret = PyObject_CallObject(func, args.Expand());

                PYConverter<RETURN> convert;
                return convert.to(ret);
            }

        private:
            PYObject m_Module;
        };
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        Scripting::Python::PYContext context;
        context.Run
        (
            R"(def mul(a, b):
                return a * b)"
        );

        auto ret = context.Invoke<double>("mul", 3.0, 4.0);
        std::cout << "RETURN VALUE IS: " << ret << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Python, so this is a purely C++ review.

## 1 PYObjectBase

#### 1.1 What is a const rvalue?

Move operations ownership of some resource generally, so how can a move operation's parameter be `const`? It logically does not make sense.

Your function...

```
template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE> PYObjectBase<AUTO_RELEASE>& operator=(
    const PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&& a_RHS);
{
    m_Raw = a_RHS.m_Raw; // valid, reading from const is fine.
    a_RHS.m_Raw = nullptr; // how is this compiling? You cannot modify a const value.
    return *this;
}
```

As my comment states, you cannot modify a `const` value. Your compiler should be giving you an error. Simply remove the `const` modifier from `a_RHS` to make it valid.

## 2 PYArgs

#### 2.1 Those are not universal references!

`PYArgs` has this constructor:

```
PYArgs(ARGS&&... args)
    : m_Tuple{ PyTuple_New(Size) } // same point from PYObjectBase; leaving the rest to you
{
    // m_Tuple = PyTuple_New(Size); delete this
    // will expand as rvalues; might as well call std::move() on the pack
    this->ConvertArgs(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}
```

The variadic template `ARGS&&... args` is not a pack forwarding references, it is an rvalue reference pack. For it to be a forwarding reference variadic template, the variadic template must be a function template parameter:

```
template<class... Types>
PYArgs(Types&&... types)
{
    m_Tuple = PyTuple_New(Size);
    // will now properly forward since Types&&... is universal reference variadic template
    this->ConvertArgs(std::forward<Types>(types)...);
}
```

As a side effect, your function:

```
template<typename...ARGS> PYArgs<ARGS...>
PYMakeArgs(ARGS&&...a_Args);
```

Is now behaving properly.

## 3 General

#### 3.1 Mark your functions as `noexcept` if they're non-throwing.

In `PYObjectBase`:

- `PYObjectBase(PyObject*);`
- `PYObjectBase();`
- `template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE> PYObjectBase(PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&&);`
- `PYObjectBase<AUTO_RELEASE>& operator=(PyObject* a_RHS);`
- `template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE> PYObjectBase<AUTO_RELEASE>& operator=(
      const PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&& a_RHS);`
- `~PYObjectBase();`
- `operator PyObject*();`

I will leave the rest of the types to you.

#### 3.2 Mark non-modifying functions as `const`

Functions that don't modify the logical object should be marked `const`.

For example:

```
operator PyObject*()    ------------>    operator PyObject*() noexcept const
{                                        {
    return m_Raw;                            return m_Raw;
}                                        }
```

Copying a pointer (`m_Raw`) is a non-throwing, and non-modifying operation. Thus, the function is additionally marked `noexcept` as well as `const`. I leave the rest of the functions to you. The benefit is that your type is now actually convertible to `PyObject*` in `const` contexts where it would otherwise not even compile. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
struct PYObjectBase
{
    operator int*()
    {
        return m_Raw;
    }

    int* m_Raw;
};

void f(PYObjectBase const& x)
{
    int* ptr = x; // compilation error; operator int*() is not marked const
}
```

#### 3.3 Initialize your members in the constructor member initialization list

You do it in some constructors, but not in others. Do it whenever possible. You can start with `PYObjectBase`'s move constructor:

```
template<bool RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>
PYObjectBase(PYObjectBase<RHS_AUTO_RELEASE>&& a_RHS)
    : m_Raw{ a_RHS.m_Raw } // member is initialized here
{
    //m_Raw = a_RHS.m_Raw; remove this line.
    a_RHS.m_Raw = nullptr;
}
```

`PYArgs`'s constructor can also be modified similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. Regarding 1) Obviously a copy-paste error. fixed it. The template was not instantiated in my code hence no compiler error. Should I use const in PyConverter<T>?

Comment: @mutex36 You could mark them `const`. You could also just make them static non-member functions of  the`PyConverter<T>` class unless you specifically need to create `PyConverter<T>` instances elsewhere.

Comment: Basically, I want PYConverter to work similar to `std::hash`, so probably won't make it static.

Answer (score 3):

You use the recursive technique to call `SetArg()`.
I personally prefer the iterative approach. This uses an initializer list.

```
        void ConvertArgs(ARGS&&... args)
        {
            std::size_t index = 0;
            // Initializer list is constructed from left to right (guranteed)
            // We use the comma operator so that each expression returns a zero
            // The first item in the list is provided in case `ARGS` is empty
            // as a zero element initializer list is not allowed.
            int ignore[] ={0, (SetArg(std::forward<ARGS>(args), index++), 0)...};
        }
        template<typename ARG>
        void SetArg(ARG&& a_Arg, const size_t a_Index)
        {
            std::cout << a_Index << "->" << a_Arg << std::endl;

            PYConverter<ARG> convert;
            PYWeakObject value = convert.from(a_Arg);

            PyTuple_SetItem(m_Tuple, a_Index, value);
        }
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of using that method? Or just personal preference?

Comment: In the old days yes (there was a template recursion limit). Nowadays not so much. There is a small advantage on source code size (this is smaller at more compact) and thus easier to read (and I like easy to read). But I think that is a tiny bit subjective and technically they deliver the same results. So I think it is a matter of style.